How lambda expresison can reference to itself before instanciation?
For fun, I tried to create a linked list with lambda functions. I tried this little code as a first step, but my experimentation went short after facing an infinite loop:
import itertools

stack = lambda: ("c", None)
stack = lambda: ("b", stack)
stack = lambda: ("a", stack)
for _ in itertools.count():
    c, stack = stack()
    print(c)

Expected output:
a
b
c
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Actual output:
a  
a
a
...

I expect the second lambda to carry a local (to second lambda) reference to the first lambda, and the third lambda to carry a local (to third lambda) reference to the second lambda.
Unexpectedly, the third lambda return a reference to itself, making the de-stack looping on the same lambda forever. This wasn't expected as stack, when the lambda is created, point to the previous lambda. How a lambda can have a reference to itself before even being created?
As we can see in Python Tutor (permalink to example), each lambda is replaced by the new lambda, each time referencing itself (except the first that return None as second element of the tuple):

This doesn't make sense for me, because of the Call by Object behavior of Python, and how I understand lambda functions carries within its closure (e.g. accessible via stack.__closure__) a cell that point to the value, but in this case, there is no closures, and even when putting the code in a function create a cell that reference the lambda expression itself:
>>> def make_stack():
...     stack = lambda: ("c", None)
...     stack = lambda: ("b", stack)
...     stack = lambda: ("a", stack)
...     return stack
... 
>>> stack = make_stack()
>>> stack.__closure__[0].cell_contents is stack
True

How is this possible for the lambda to have a reference to itself, an object not even created yet?

function objects aren't "atomic"; they are built from numerous distinct pieces that get assembled by Python while executing the def statement before being finally bound to some name.

Also, the lambda expressions have no reference to the object. The two latter functions created by the lambda expression have free variables named stack that refer to whatever is bound to the name stack when the function is called. As long as you don't do anything silly, stack refers to the function you intended it to refer to.

Your code works exactly the same as if you had used different names like s1 = lambda: ("c", none); s2 = lambda: ("b", s1); return lambda: ("a": s2).


How lambda expresison can reference to itself before instanciation?

The same way a function can call itself to perform a recursive call.
In Python, the scope of a function (not only lambda) is limited to its parameters and any references from the outer scope. Call by Object only concerns parameters, this means that a lambda (and functions) references to outer-scope variables will access outer-scope values of those variables, not their current values at the function definition. As a result, when a lambda (or a function) is called, it uses the most recent value of the referenced variable at the time of the call.
For example:
>>> ham = lambda: bacon
>>> ham()
NameError: name 'bacon' is not defined
>>> bacon = 142
>>> ham()
142

Here, the lambda function ham references the variable bacon. When ham is called, it returns the current value of bacon, which is 142, not the value at the time the lambda was defined.
It is similar to this:
>>> def ham():
...     return bacon
>>> ham()
NameError: name 'bacon' is not defined
>>> bacon = 142
>>> ham()
142

This behavior also applies to closures. Even when the lambda captures variables from a scope that has been exited, it retains a reference to those variables. However, it will always use the most recent value of the variable. For instance:
>>> def spam():
...    ham = lambda: bacon
...    bacon = 142
...    return ham
...
>>> eggs = spam()
>>> eggs()
142

In this example, the lambda function ham retains a reference to bacon even after the function spam exits. When eggs() (the returned lambda) is called, it evaluates the reference bacon and returns its last value, 142.
If you want a lambda to use a specific value at the time of its definition rather than tracking a variable that may change later, you can use default arguments in the lambda. This allows you to pass the current value explicitly to the lambda and avoid the reference being updated:
lambda spam=eggs: spam  # return the value eggs had when the lambda was created

This technique "locks in" the value of eggs as the default argument spam.
Here's an example of applying this principle to fix the original code:
import itertools

stack = lambda c="c", s=None: (c, s)
stack = lambda c="b", s=stack: (c, s)
stack = lambda c="a", s=stack: (c, s)
for _ in itertools.count():
    c, stack = stack()
    print(c)

Output:
a
b
c
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Python Tutor memory map (permalink here):


Technically, it's not calling itself. It's calling a previously defined function bound to the same name that the new function will be bound to. The fact that you keep reusing the name stack doesn't change the fact that you have three different function objects, with the third and final stack keeping a reference to the second function, and the second function keeping a reference to the first one.

Also, I think the real question is how stack.__closure__ gets a reference to stack itself, not how you write Python code that can (appear to) reference itself.

since stack have no closure in the example, it is unrelated. Closure is a way to keep the object alive, almost nothing else.

the third have a ref to the second because of the default param, and that is intended and desired in this case.

You don’t have a closure, but the OP does, and that’s what I think is the main thrust of the question.

Look at the third snippet : there is a closure here.
In the OP, it is showed that the closure doesn't change anything to the behavior.
Closures is unrelated to this issue. How Python handle ref from outer-scope is.
